# Create and run interceptors in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'd like to create an interceptor and to register it in Simple Injector. I create an interceptor based on Simple Injector tutorial ([here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/InterceptionExtensions.html)).

The interceptor will be using to authorize users, I need to read method parameters and then check the user has authorization to perform that method.

Note, there is a authorization attribute that receives a permisson name to perform method.

Example:

```
[Authorize("SaveProductsAuthorization")]
public void SaveProducts(filter, dataToSave) 
{...}
```

Here is the interceptor registration

```
container.InterceptWith<MedTimeAuthorizeInterceptor>(
    serviceType => serviceType == typeof(IInterceptionEnabler));

container.RegisterSingleton<AuthorizeInterceptor>();
```

In my `ProfessionalController` there is a `IInterceptionEnable`, like this:

```
public class ProfissionalController : ApiController, IInterceptionEnabler
```

I put a break point into Intercept method in Authorize Interceptor and nothing happended.

What's wrong here? Maybe is the interception registration wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Interception can only be applied to interfaces being returned. You howeverf are trying to intercept a controller, but controllers are always returned by their concrete type and **concrete types cannot be intercepted**.

It doesn't really matter here that the controller *implements* the `IInterceptionEnabler`; interception will only take place if you call `GetInstance<IInterceptionEnabler>()`.